# XSL transformation based on descendant values?

Tags: xml, xslt

We have some software where we recieve XML data feeds that we translate to match our feed parser. I'm working on bringing in a new feed and I'm having a tough time splitting out one of the categories due to how the source feed comes in. I can't change our XML format or theirs, so I'm stuck with having to do this in nothing but XSL(T).

In this theoretical example, I have a list of products that will be displayed in a few catalogs that get generated. We treat products with 100% markup differently than items with 80% markup. Ordinarily we get the higher marked up items as a separate product, but in this case it's embedded much lower in the node tree.

The XML we get looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<products>
    <product>
        <name>lawnmower</name>
        <prices>
            <price>
                <supplier>amazon</supplier>
                <markup>100%</markup>
                <price>$200</price>
            </price>
            <price>
                <supplier>newegg</supplier>
                <markup>80%</markup>
                <price>$160</price>
            </price>
            <price>
                <supplier>home depot</supplier>
                <markup>80%</markup>
                <price>$150</price>
            </price>
        </prices>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>laptop</name>
        <prices>
            <price>
                <supplier>newegg</supplier>
                <markup>80%</markup>
                <price>$1000</price>
            </price>
        </prices>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>my little pony</name>
        <prices>
            <price>
                <supplier>amazon</supplier>
                <markup>80%</markup>
                <price>$50</price>
            </price>
            <price>
                <supplier>newegg</supplier>
                <markup>80%</markup>
                <price>$40</price>
            </price>
        </prices>
    </product>
</products>
```

And we want to convert it to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<prodlist>
    <products>
        <product category="lawnmower">
            <price supplier="newegg">$160</price>
            <price supplier="home depot">$150</price>
        </product>
        <product category="lawnmower100">
            <price supplier="amazon">$200</price>
        </product>
        <product category="laptop">
            <price supplier="newegg">$1000</price>
        </product>
        <product category="my little pony">
            <price supplier="amazon">$50</price>
        </product>
    </products>
</prodlist>
```

I'm using some XSL that looks roughly like this (I've clipped out all of the surrounding XSL in order to attempt a little bit of brevity):

```
<xsl:template match="products">
    <xsl:element name="product">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test = "name = 'lawnmower' and prices/price/markup = '100%'">
                <xsl:attribute name="category">lawnmower100</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="prices" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:attribute name="category">
                    <xsl:value-of select="name" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="prices" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Using that is giving me some bad results though; everything for lawnmowers is getting pulled into the "lawnmower100" category, giving me a result that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<prodlist>
    <products>
        <product category="lawnmower100">
            <price supplier="amazon">$200</price>
            <price supplier="newegg">$160</price>
            <price supplier="home depot">$150</price>
        </product>
        <product category="laptop">
            <price supplier="newegg">$1000</price>
        </product>
        <product category="my little pony">
            <price supplier="amazon">$50</price>
        </product>
    </products>
</prodlist>
```

I'm not too sure how I should be selecting out the 100% marked up items, but whatever I'm doing now isn't working. I've played with  and  but I don't think I'm using them correctly, since I keep ending up with this result.

I hope I've provided enough detail that this makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm very much mistaken, that should be something like:

```
<xsl:template match="products">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="product[prices/price/markup='100%']" mode="hundred"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="product[prices/price/markup='80%']" mode="eighty"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="product" mode="hundred">
  <xsl:element name="product">
    <xsl:attribute name="category"><xsl:value-of select="name" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="prices/price[markup='100%']"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="product" mode="eighty">
  <xsl:element name="product">
    <xsl:attribute name="category"><xsl:value-of select="concat(name,'80')" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="prices/price[markup='80%']"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="price">
  <!-- individual price processing here -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hot damn, that worked perfectly! Thank you for saving my sanity!